# Within container dpkg install from deb file fails with license could not be presented

Tags: docker, dpkg

Host running `ubuntu 20.04`

Docker container base is nvidia's `nvcr.io/nvidia/deepstream:6.0.1-triton` which should be based on `ubuntu 20.04`

Trying to install the graph_composer deb file from
https://developer.nvidia.com/deepstream-getting-started

```
root@xxxx:/workspace/downloads# dpkg -i graph_composer-1.0.0_x86_64.deb 
(Reading database ... 72950 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack graph_composer-1.0.0_x86_64.deb ...
SOFTWARE LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR NVIDIA SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT KITS could not be presented
dpkg: error processing archive graph_composer-1.0.0_x86_64.deb (--install):
 new graph-composer package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 graph_composer-1.0.0_x86_64.deb
```

The same deb file I was able to run on the host. It displays a GUI to accept the license before installation starts. So I'm thinking the docker image is missing something that is used to display license files, I've tried:

1. install xterm and check the x11 is working, I think it is since the xterm appears
2. install dialog, did not change anything
3. do dpkg on host, which worked
4. `apt-get update && apt-get install -f debconf` which didnt do anything, debconf already at latest version
5. `debconf-set-selections <<< 'graph-composer deepstream-reference-graphs/present-eula boolean true'` which was based on running `sudo debconf-show graph-composer` on host. same error still occurs

Comment: Docker is all about being non-interactive. It disables the question interface. If the nvidia package is correctly done, it should store the information. On the system where you succesfully installed it, try: `debconf-show graph_composer-1.0.0` to check how is the information stored.

Comment: it required sudo, but it returned nothing

Comment: `sudo debconf-show graph-composer` returns
`* deepstream-reference-graphs/present-eula: true`

Comment: Oh the package name doesn't match the package filename? Ah right the first `_` is already an anomaly.

Comment: i just tried --listowners and checked the one that was most similar

Comment: You'll have to provide the Dockerfile to help an answer

Answer (score 1):

Despite only using `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` as arguments in my own Dockerfile, turns out whoever prepared `nvcr.io/nvidia/deepstream:6.0.1-triton` had added it to ENV

Therefore the solution was to set it to `readline`.

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline dpkg -i graph_composer-1.0.0_x86_64.deb
```

(installing `dialog` and then setting it to `dialog` would work as well.)

thanks to user @A.B for pointing me in the rough direction